Safe C++: questions about borrow-checking
I've started reading the Safe C++ proposal and have some questions about the example in section 1.5.1 Lifetime safety. Direct link to the godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/8KabhKP97
The example is this:
#feature on safety
#include <std2.h>

using namespace std2;

int main() safe {
  // Populate the vector with views with a nice mixture of lifetimes.
  vector<string_view> views { };

  // string_view with /static lifetime.
  mut views.push_back("From a string literal");

  // string_view with outer scope lifetime.
  string s1("From string object 1");
  mut views.push_back(s1);

  {
    // string_view with inner scope lifetime.
    string s2("From string object 2");
    mut views.push_back(s2);

    // s2 goes out of scope. views now holds dangling pointers into
    // out-of-scope data.
  }

  // Print the strings. s2 already fell out of scope, so this should
  // be a borrowck violation. `views` now contains objects that hold
  // dangling pointers.
  println("Printing from the outer scope:");
  for(string_view sv : views)
    println(sv);
}

Which results in the expected compilation errors:
$ circle string_view.cxx -I ../libsafecxx/single-header/
safety: during safety checking of int main() safe
  borrow checking: string_view.cxx:30:24
    for(string_view sv : views) 
                         ^
  use of views depends on expired loan
  drop of s2 between its shared borrow and its use
  s2 declared at string_view.cxx:19:12
      string s2("From string object 2"); 
             ^
  loan created at string_view.cxx:20:25
      mut views.push_back(s2); 
                          ^


How does the compiler know that std2::vector holds on to the string_view after push_back returns, and that looping the vector will be a use-after-drop? push_back could just use the stringview as a temporary (or ignore it completely). Or it could use it to instantiate a new string on the heap, and push a string_view for that into the vector. I don't see any annotations in the signature of std2::vector::push_back that tell the compiler: I'll keep this string_view alive and iterate over it!
std2::vector has no erase method(s) - is this just not implemented yet or is it on purpose?
If we had a way to erase elements from the vector, and we erased the inner-scope string_view from the vector before iterating over it, could the compiler detect that and greenlight the loop? I can't imagine how it could possibly figure out that the inner string is now no longer referenced.

If I'm just missing some basic principles here, I'm also happy if you can guide me to where I can educate myself.
PS: I know it's one question per post, but I feel these are closely enough related that splitting them would be more confusing. Also, I'm unsure what to tag this apart from c++. borrowing/borrow-checker seem rust specific.

If it instantiates a string on the heap, how would it be deleted? It's a potential memory leak when the vector is destroyed. You can't to that in a language without garbage collection.

There are some simple cases where the compiler might be able to detect that the bad references have all been removed, but not in general. Imagine if the push and erase operations are in conditional code.

@Barmar regarding your first comment, I feel like that's beside the point. What I'm saying is: the function could be called foo_bar taking the same args, and just print the string_view instead of storing it. How does the borrow checker know that the loop is a problem after calling push_back, but not after calling foo_bar?

It knows that any reference to vector elements is invalid after leaving the inner block, because that added a pointer to a local variable to the vector. The loop is just an example, but there would be a similar problem with cout << string_view[i]; for any value of i.

Borrow checker might forbid code which might work, but invalid from lifetime checking as just printing views[0] Demo.

Lifetime of string_view in vector goes from static, outer scope, inner scope(, and invalid). Any usage out of scope of lifetime is flagged.

@Barmar my question is how it knows that the pointer was added to the vector. Is it just a rule: if you pass any borrow to a mutating method, then we assume the object holds on to that borrow for the rest of its lifetime?

The borrow checker keeps track (during compile time) who owns the object, and who has (temporarily) borrowed the object.

As far as I can tell it doesn't matter whether or not push_back actually uses or how it uses the string_view argument. Because the argument string_view holds a shared borrow of s2, and push_back is a non-const member function so that it can modify the vector object itself, it is assumed that the vector will also hold a reference to s2 after push_back. Any use of an non-annotated member function of views after s2 then goes out-of-scope produces the same diagnostic. The implicit destructor call works only because it is annotated as [[unsafe::drop_only(T)]].

This case is happen often in network program. and we will use std::weak_ptr<std::string> or std::shared_ptr<std::string>  instead of string_view in vector<string_view> . So no need any borrow check, just use right tool.

@user17732522 thanks, that makes sense. Although it seems very limiting. Maybe a mutable member can also be annotated to show it doesn't store its parameter. I think this also answers my 3rd question: erase would not allow to remove the diagnostic. Interesting.

@Wutz It is not really all that limiting. It just enforces lifetime rules that should be followed anyway. If the vector outlives one of the objects it references, then there is already something wrong with the ownership design. That should not happen. Sure, there are certain cases where it will still work if used carefully (and some where it is necessary), but these are exceptions to the rule that would require careful consideration and probably also comments to make clear why the specific exception works. These cases would presumably be served by unsafe or other annotations.

@Wutz Even if you have erase, in the example, in order for ownership to be correct, you must be sure that s2 is erased from the vector again before the scope is left. How do you convince yourself that if you have some more complex logic in there that somewhere uses erase at the end of the scope erase has actually erased all problematic elements? That's generally an undecidable question. So it would probably be better to modify the structure so that there is no need to reason about this. For example you could introduce a second vector limited to the inner scope.

@user17732522 what you're saying makes sense to me, thanks. Just one thing: when I was talking about "limiting", I wasn't thinking of vectors in particular, but rather that this storage assumption is made for any mutating method taking a viewlike parameter. I can easily imagine a class having such a method which doesn't actually store the parameter. I hope there is an annotation for this.

Is it just me, or does it seem like Safe-C++ is trying to turn C++ into Rust?
